# What is the difference between the X-Men and the Inhumans?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, inhumans

As I understand it, both the X-Men and the Inhumans receive their powers due to their innate genetics (as opposed to supers that got it from an external source, like Spider-Man who got it from a radioactive spider).

In the mainstream, Earth-616 comics universe, what is the difference between these two groups? Do they have different sets of genes that both happen to express themselves as superpowers? Or is there some other important difference?

Comment: The main difference is that the X-Men sell hundreds of thousands of comics and the Inhumans sell tens of thousands of comics